# Where is the hardware write protection screw in an Asus CX1 Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook, asus

I'm trying to install Windows onto my Asus CX1 (CX1500CN) Chromebook, but I cannot find the screw. Even after taking apart the whole laptop, I have yet to find it.

Where is the hardware write protection screw?

Comment: More information might help. What tutorial are you following? Have others installed Windows on that model, and can you provide a link to that?

Comment: Not sure this was downvoted.  I think its a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Note that with this hardware it wouldn't be a pleasurable experience to run windows.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the [service manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Commercial_NB/Service_Manual/E18002_CX1400_1500_SM_WEB.pdf) nor the [user manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Commercial_NB/CX1400CNA/0409_E17488_CX1500CNA_B.pdf) mention this screw.

It seems that newer devices use the battery instead:

> In newer devices, we've moved away from the WP signal being controlled by a physical screw and to a separate chip controlling the WP signal.  That way we have more flexible control over the WP signal. It still takes long time and physical presence to diable write protection, and can be configured such that only the device owners are authorized to disable write protection.

...

> If you don‘t want to go through the CCD open process or don’t have a
> suzyQ, you can open the case and remove the battery to disable
> hardware write protect.

...

> - Disassemble the device, locate the battery connector, remove the
>   battery connector from the PCB to disconnect the battery.
> - Reassemble
>   the device, insert the original OEM charger (necessary since the
>   battery is no longer providing power to the system), then boot to
>   developer mode.

[Source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/write_protection.md)